# Flutter: how to avoid automatic scrolling in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm building a chat application and I've reached the part where I'm creating the actual chat interface. I decided to use the `ListView.builder()` constructor, as I'm working with potentially a great amount of data (messages). The layout, and my code in general, look something like [this](https://dartpad.dev/2c46c4048ddf68401951c2c0d99aaf27).

I want to preserve the scrolling position at any time, unless the user explicitly scrolls away. Here comes the first issue: when the software keyboard appears, or the size of the input field changes, I would like the bottom of the messages area to stay visible, and the older (ie. above) messages to get pushed out of the screen. You know, the way it works in Messenger, etc. However, it doesn't work like that. The older messages stay visible, and the newer ones get pushed put.

To achieve this, I tried to set the `reverse` argument to `true`. While it indeed solved the above issues, it created a newer one. Whenever a new message is added (since it is "reversed", I have to prepend the messages list), the whole messages area appears to "jump". It is, I believe, due to the fact that the since `ListView` is reversed, the item with index 0 is always the newest message.

However, I don't like this behavior. It doesn't seem intuitive to the user, who either expects to be scrolled down to the latest message, or be shown a floating UI element indicating that there are new messages.

Question #1: can I somehow disable/change the above behavior for reversed list? I'm thinking of a callback that calculates the "old" offset and instantly scrolls to that location when a new message is added. Not sure if it's possible or if it fits the pattern.

Question #2: I though about not using a reversed list, and instead add something like a `SizeChangedLayoutNotifier`, listening to the size changes of the `ListView`, and scroll to position accordingly. This, too, looks hacky, though.

Generally speaking, I would like to achieve a Messenger-like (or really, any other similar app) behavior. Opening the software keyboard should "push up" the messages, and when a new message arrives, there shouldn't be any jump or automatic scrolling.

---

UPDATE #1: found a workaround, but I would rather not go with it. Whenever an item gets added, I get the `position.maxScrollExtent` value of the `ScrollController`, then, after updating the state, I get the new value. Subtract the new value from the old, then subtract the difference from the current offset, and finally `jumpTo` this value. And *voilà*, we are at the same message. This has multiple drawbacks, though:

- By the nature of this workaround, it's jumpy. You have to know that the new max. scroll extent will be to calculate the difference, because you have no way of knowing how long the new message is, and what the height of its bubble's going to be
- Race condition? You have to await for an arbitrary duration (for the lack of a better method, any takers?) in order to see the value update. It *works* in the emulator, but will it work on users' devices?
- It's not declarative/reactive. In my local example, I *know* when an item/message gets added. However, when using streams, I would need a listener to capture each time this happens, and it would be a lot of headache.

For the reasons above, I decided not to use this workaround.

---

Thanks.

Comment: To avoid scrolling of a listview you can set this in you ListView(
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
)

Comment: Yeah, it could be applied conditionally. However, a message may arrive at any one time, meaning, if the user is currently in the process of scrolling, it would come to an abrupt stop, which would be pretty unfavorable from a UX perspective.

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question: please clarify how it doesn't show any research effort, is unclear or otherwise unuseful. I'm willing to update it accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Hello Riwen! Did you find a solution to your question? I'm exactly in the same point, building a chat app and sadly jumping the scroll when a new message arrives. If you find something, please kindly share it. You have my upvote, hihihi

Answer (score -1):

You can change your default scrollPhysics to this class to retain the current position when a new message is added.
And the user can still scroll through his messages.

I'll just put the code here for someone who still search for a solution to this.

```
class PositionRetainedScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
    final bool? shouldRetain;
    const PositionRetainedScrollPhysics({
       super.parent,
       this.shouldRetain = true,
    });

   @override
   PositionRetainedScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor){
       return PositionRetainedScrollPhysics(
       parent: buildParent(ancestor),
       shouldRetain: shouldRetain,
       );
     }

   @override
   double adjustPositionForNewDimensions({
       required ScrollMetrics oldPosition,
       required ScrollMetrics newPosition,
       required bool isScrolling,
       required double velocity,
    }) {
       final position = super.adjustPositionForNewDimensions(
          oldPosition: oldPosition,
          newPosition: newPosition,
          isScrolling: isScrolling,
          velocity: velocity,
       );

       // Check if the new position exceeds the scrollable extents
       if (newPosition.maxScrollExtent < oldPosition.maxScrollExtent) {
          return position.clamp(
          oldPosition.minScrollExtent,
          oldPosition.maxScrollExtent,
       );
      }

      final diff = newPosition.maxScrollExtent - oldPosition.maxScrollExtent;

      if (!isScrolling && shouldRetain) {
        return position + diff;
      } else {
        return position;
      }
    }
  }
```